# How to show the React Toastbar on Page change/redirect by button click?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to show a Toast Success Message when a button is clicked, after button click, the page  will redirect and the toast message would be shown.

In Page 1:

```
const toSecondPage = () => {
  history.push(`/secondPage`);
};
...
<Button onClick={toSecondPage}>Click Me!</Button>
```

I'm able to redirect to /secondPage but not aware of how to show the toast message on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With react router you can pass a state to the page you redirect to.

```
<Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/secondPage',
            state: { showToast: true }
        }}
/>
```

in secondPage :

```
if(this.props.location.state.showToast){
    //show toast
}
```

Instead of a button with an onClick use a link from react router :

```
    <Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/secondPage",
    state: { showToast: true }
  }}
>Click me</Link>
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'll try implementing your solution. Thank you.